# Pass a property of a Linq entity in a method to set and get result

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to pass in a property of a Linq entity to be used by my method.  I can easily pass a property to be queried

```
Func<Entities.MyEntity, ResultType> GetProperty = ent => ent.Property;
```

However this returns ResultType and cannot be used to set the property.

I thought about using reflection to get a propertyInfo, but this will let me fetch the property but then I can't use Linq syntax to call my property.  Is there any guru out there that knows how to do this?

I have a hunch I could do it by constructing a chunk of an expression tree and applying it onto the query...

I was really hoping to do something like:

```
var value = myQueryEntity.CallMagicFunction();  //typesafe
myQueryEntity.CallMagicFunction() = value; //typesafe
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, an expression tree should work; for **basic** member access (a field/property directly off the object):

```
static MemberInfo ReadMember(LambdaExpression expr)
{
    if(expr == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("expr");
    MemberExpression me = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
    if(me == null || !ReferenceEquals(me.Expression, expr.Parameters[0])) {
        throw new ArgumentException("expr");
    }
    return me.Member;
}
```

with

```
Expression<Func<Customer, int>> func = c => c.Id;
MemberInfo member = ReadMember(func);
// for simplicity assume prop:
PropertyInfo prop = (PropertyInfo)member;
```

From there you can do pretty much anything; in particular you can get the `get`/`set` accessors (if you want to create a delegate), or use `GetValue` / `SetValue`.

Note that in .NET 4.0 you can set properties directly on an `Expression` (but the C# compiler *doesn't* add any extra support for this, so you'd need to write your own `Expression` by hand).

Comment: So this uses an expression tree and reflection to access the propertyinfo object.  I realise that I can call the member and set the member from here.  I would have thought that there would be a typesafe way of doing this without resorting to the getvalue/setvalue.  Or should I start programming in python...

Comment: @Spence - sure; just use `obj.Id = ...` ;-p OK, more seriously, you can create a typed delegate - for example a `Func<Customer,int>` / `Action<Customer,int>` by using `Delegate.CreateDelegate` - is that what you would need? In 4.0 `dynamic` may also be of interest.